# How to change the order of R lib path within a conda environment permanently

Tags: r, conda

I created a conda environment that installed a directory for R library packages, i.e., LIB = "/anaconda3/envs/aaa/lib/R/library". When I activated the environment, the tool did not work due to the wrong R library loading. After checking .libPaths(), I found that the other directory that I set for R library package outside the conda environment is before LIB.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/software/Rpackage"
[2] "/anaconda3/envs/aaa/lib/R/library"
```

After deactivating the conda environment, by checking .libPaths(), only "/software/Rpackage" is displayed, which is set perviously for general purposes.

May I ask how to change the order of LIB before "/software/Rpackage" when activating the conda environment or only display LIB? Meanwhile, once deactivating the conda environment, "/software/Rpackage" is still kept.

Comment: Could you please consider adding `PATH = "/anaconda3/envs/aaa/lib/R/library"` at the start of the question, and then replacing `"/anaconda3/envs/aaa/lib/R/library"` with `PATH` thereafter? That would simplify your question a lot.

Comment: @medium-dimensional Actually that edit made the question super confusing, since `PATH`, in that exact spelling, has [an established meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) which differs from the one used here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Oops, yes, I understand. I could have been mindful about that.